# How to find number of circles or number of objects in this image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

[Image from which I want to find out number of objects/circles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpq93.png)

I want to find Total number of circles/nodules in this image using OpenCV with C++.

For which I have written this code:

```
src = imread("src.bmp");   //src is source image 
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);   // Gray scale convert
Mat bw = src_gray > 128;
imshow("Gray Scaled Source",src_gray);  

Canny(src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3); /// Detect edges using canny


/// Find contours
findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

/// Draw contours
drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3);

cout<<contours.size();   // total no of contours
```

By this code my answer is : 117

But the right answer is: 62

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to extract the circle/objects from the given image

```
Mat src, src_gray,binarySeg;
vector< vector <Point> > contours;
vector <Vec4i> hierarchy;

src = imread("src.bmp");
cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(src_gray,binarySeg,75,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
morphologyEx(binarySeg,binarySeg,MORPH_DILATE,Mat::ones(3,3,CV_32F),Point(-1,-1),1);

findContours(binarySeg, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
cout<<contours.size();
```

What happens here is this, you threshold the image first based on the values that you give. Then you do a dilate operations to remove the small areas. After that you find the number of contours.

---

Comment: On which image I have to apply canny function? "canny_output" how to get this image?

Comment: Sorry, that was an error from my part. The code has been updated

Comment: Still without canny how will it detect edges of the object? I've tried your updated code but it is not showing any object in the image.

Comment: After you use the morphologyEx, use imshow for binarySeg. You should see the objects in black and background in white

Comment: number of contours are still really high i.e. 277 comparing ans 62 and imshow("binarySeg",binarySeg) is still not showing proper image.

Comment: I ran the above code on the image you linked. I got the number of contours as 62

Comment: Can you give me your email ID or something because I got the answer for this result but for another similar kind of images I'm not getting right answer. Thank you for your help.